# Do class variables in python behaves as instance variable when we instantiate an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables, class-variables

Consider the following example:

```
class Ciao():
    a = 1 
    def whatIsIt(self):
        print(self.a)

i = Ciao()
i.a = 2
i.whatIsIt() #Returns 2
```

I am creating an instance of the class Ciao, modifying the class variable and then printing it in the last line. To me, the class variable a, after having create the object i, behaves completely as the instance variable in this code snippet.

```
class Ciao2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
    def whatIsIt(self):
        print(self.a)
i = Ciao2()
i.a = 2
i.whatIsIt() #Returns 2
```

Is there any fundamental difference between a class and an instance variable after having instantiate the object?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a fundamental difference. It can be seen when the variables are mutable (e.g. lists), and you work with several instances of the same class. Changes made to a class variable will carry over to all the instances, but changes made to an instance variable will not:

```py
class Ciao():
    a = [1]
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = [1]
        
        
i1 = Ciao()
print(i1.a, i1.b)  # [1] [1]
i1.a.append(2)
i1.b.append(2)
print(i1.a, i1.b)  # [1, 2] [1, 2]

i2 = Ciao()
print(i2.a, i2.b)  # [1, 2] [1]
```

Comment: Ahh, that is interesting and  counter-intuitive. Suppose you are reassigning the class variable (i.e. i1.a = 5, this will not be propagated to class variables of the other instances i.e., i1.a = 5 while i2.a = [1]  ). On the other hand, as you show for mutable elements, the change is propagated. Do you know why there is this discrepancy in the behavior? Is there something going on under the hood when reassign a class variable?

Comment: @Tommaso Bendinelli I think it boils down to the usual difference between mutable and immutable objects. When you reassign an immutable variable, what really happens is that a new variable is created, whereas when you reassign a mutable variable, the original value is changed.

Comment: mmm, probably yeah